# Sorting the lists in dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to know to sort each list of a data frame column(pandas). For example:

```
id       values
------------------------
 1      ['cdf','abc','efg']
 2      ['xyz' ,'rsy','abc']
```

Expected :

```
 id       values
------------------------
 1      ['abc','cdf','efg']
 2      ['abc' ,'rsy','xyz']
```

Thanks:
I would also like to know the same if comma seperated strings are present instead of list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply using **`apply`** with **`sorted`**

```
df['values'].apply(sorted)

0    [abc, cdf, efg]
1    [abc, rsy, xyz]
Name: values, dtype: object
```

For comma separated values, thanks @AChampion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'values': ['cdf, abc, efg', 'xyz, rsy, abc']})
df['values'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))

0     abc, efg,cdf
1     abc, rsy,xyz
Name: values, dtype: object
```

You can also use a list comprehension to increase performance:

```
df['values'] = [','.join(sorted(i.split(','))) for i in df['values']]
```

Comment: And `df['values'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))` for comma separated strings.